# getrawtransaction doesn't work for every transaction with -txindex=1?

Tags: blockchain, bitcoind, bitcoin-core

i put txindex=1 in bitcoin config and reindex blockchain after that when i call getrawtransaction for some transactions didn't exist in my wallet and work well like:

**[Working]**

```
getrawtransaction d2632db404d0cdff861278f369b8dfc09a8e84e9af76558dcc6457909544cf1e 1
```

but with this transtions didn't work why ?

**[Not Working]**

```
getrawtransaction 37e3abcbfc9b2b984fb34e2605d512614a4a2a507fe50fb4b639c08d29137f34 1

getrawtransaction 7bdaefdd1819440fdd988538ad59ef0d9a5a899b4db7446bfea5dee3d88dfb1b 1
```

Comment: have you tried it again? I just called the not working commands and they work fine for me

Comment: second one is working with me but first one didn't work : getrawtransaction 37e3abcbfc9b2b984fb34e2605d512614a4a2a507fe50fb4b639c08d29137f34 1

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that when you asked the question the transaction had not been confirmed. They have since been confirmed and they will show up now.

Comment: no sir this translations had been confirmed

Comment: @Dev777, check that your client is synchronised and `getblockcount` matches Blockchain.info.